# Entity framework does not see relationship in a Fully Defined Relationship

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

I have defined this recursive entity:

```
    public class Prefix
    {
        public int PrefixId { get; set; }

        // Many to one relation
        public Nullable<int> PlcObjectId { get; set; }
        public virtual PlcObject PlcObject { get; set; }

        // Many to one relation (! Recursion !)
        public Nullable<int> ParentPrefixId { get; set; }
        public virtual Prefix ParentPrefix { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string NodeName { get; set; }
        ...
```

Now it does understand that `PlcObjectId` and `PlcObject` should map to the same column. But it maps `ParentPrefixId` and `ParentPrefix` to separate columns. How do I make them map to the same column?

Thanks!

[Image taken from pgAdmin (PostgreSQL)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0g4t.png)

Comment: After some more searching I found the answer here:
[One to many recursive relationship with Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720369/one-to-many-recursive-relationship-with-code-first)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue comes from the fact that for any `Prefix` many `Prefix`s can reference it. To map that relationship you need your Prefix class to contain a parameterless constructor like this:

```
    public Prefix()
    {
        Prefixes = new HashSet<Prefix>();
    }
```

P.s. The reason your PlcObject column maps fine is because there's no recursion. Your Prefix object needs to be handled like the sender and receiver of a many-to-one relationship

Edit:

You also need to add this field to your class

```
        public ICollection<Prefix> Prefixes { get; set; }
```

You can name this whatever your want like ChildPrefixes or DependentPrefixes.

Comment: Hello Tim,
Thanks for your answer! I do have both those things.
`[ForeignKey("ParentPrefixId")]` did it for me.